# Which rewrite has the most close meaning to the original?

Tags: grammar, meaning

From Roger Berry. (1997). Collins Cobuild English Guides: DETERMINERS&QUANTITIERS. p. 7.

> In this book the meaning of 'quantifier' is slightly different. It
> refers to words that can be used in a particular pattern,***that is***, when
> they are followed by 'of' and then a definite noun group.

Rewrite 1(removing 'that is'):

> In this book the meaning of 'quantifier' is slightly different. It
> refers to words that can be used in a particular pattern when
> they are followed by 'of' and then a definite noun group.

Rewrite 2(adding parentheses):

> In this book the meaning of 'quantifier' is slightly different. It
> refers to words that can be used in a particular pattern (that is,
> when they are followed by 'of' and then a definite noun group.)

I am not sure whether 'when they are followed by 'of'...' is a adverbial clause modifing 'that can be used in a particular pattern' or a clause introducing by 'that is' to give extra infomation to 'a particular pattern'.

Or,there is another explanation?

Comment: You don't say why you need a rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

It does not “give additional information” about the particular pattern, it specifies the pattern.

And for that reason your version with the parenthesis fails. After all, **every** word can be used in **some** particular pattern, so if your parenthesis were elided, the remaining sentence would be practically tautological.

And your first rewrite obscures the fact that the *when*-headed prepositional phrase constitutes the pattern’s specification. It allows readers down the [garden path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) of parsing the sentence along the lines of *You can knit socks from a pattern when you’re not comfortable creating a design on the fly*.

Comment: So, how to understand the 'that is' in the original sentence?

Comment: Its function is to indicate that the specification follows. Compare *After the party there remained one problem, **that is**, what to do with all of the leftover food*.

Comment: I got it.So,replacing the parentheses to a dash would be another alternative? Like this, 'In this book the meaning of 'quantifier' is slightly different. It refers to words that can be used in a particular pattern –that is, when they are followed by 'of' and then a definite noun group.'